# How to change color of row that contains different value using Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular7

How can I give a red color to a row that has a different value by using Angular 7?

I have tried to give a red color to the row in the HTML table that has different values on the same row. If each `td` on same row has different values from each cell behind it will give the row a red font color. I tried that by using jQuery and it run successfully, but I cannot do that using Angular 7. How can I do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  MakeColorForDifferentContent();
});

function MakeColorForDifferentContent() {
  $("table tr").each((_, tr) => {
    var tempValue = $($(tr).find('td:first-child')).text();
    var tds = $(tr).find('td:not(:first-child)');
    var isDiff = false;
    
    tds.each((_, td) => {
      if ($(td).text() !== tempValue) {
        isDiff = true;
        return true;
      }
    });

    if (isDiff)
      $(tr).css('color', 'red');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <col width="500">
  <tr bgcolor="#6699FF" width="100%">
    <th>Part1</th>
    <th>Part2</th>
    <th>Part3</th>
    <th>Part4</th>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>17</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: DO NOT MIX JQuery and Angular. They are both (pretty expensive) JS frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use jQuery with Angular (at least for DOM manipulation)
2. The way to do conditional styling in Angular is with the class directive

This is a rough demonstration of the techniques you should be familiar with for doing this kind of task:

```
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows" [class.red-row]="isDiff(row)">
<td *ngFor="let cell of row">{{cell}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In your typescript:

```
rows: number[][];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.rows = [
    [12, 12, 12, 12],
    [12, 15, 12, 12]
  ];
}

isDiff(row: number[]): boolean {
  const tempValue: number = row[0];
  for (let i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (tempValue !== row[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

In your style sheet:

```
.red-row {
  color: red;
}
```